# Auto-Login via URL with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, autologin

I'm trying to do an auto login with symfony2 and a special kind of url. Just like [described here](http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/manually-authenticate-symfony-2-user/).

But when I use the symfony2 debug toolbar, I notice that it says: "Not authenticated". But I have a session, I have a user object and it all seems to work just fine. Why is the debug toolbar saying this?

And is there something wrong with the method zadbuchy is describing? I'm using symfony 2.1.6.

Edit: I know that this may not the 'securest' way to login (Thanks to @Bart for the discussion), but I'm curious why symfony2 doesn't recognize the login correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
$firewall = "support_secured_area";
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));

// Fire the login event (Suggestion from the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work :( ).
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->getRequest(), $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

Comment: May I add that this doesn't seem like a very safe way to authenticate users.

Comment: Thanks for that remark. I considered that while designing it. I know the security concerns, but the alternative (write E-mails) is equally secure (because S/MIME and GnuPG are not applicable).
The main use is to provide a simple way to request tickets and view the ticket status. So I think it's ok.

Comment: Not entirely true. An e-mail is mostly a onetime event. A user should be able to change their passwords and be encouraged to do so if send by mail. This is not possible with fixed urls. You can change the url, but it is as safe as authenticating with only a username.

Comment: That's true. The way to go would be challenge-response authentication, which would enhance security a lot (and also keeping the defined use cases). That would also require the auto-login feature :o). Making the system a "you-have-to-register-first" process, would raise the hurdle a lot. I barely get tickets currently and most of them are at most 2 sentences. So this doesn't seem the right way to go for me.

Comment: Or I could use a one-time pass on every login. That would be easier... Anyway, I'm curious why Symfony2 doesn't recognize the login method.

Comment: Have you redirected them to behind the firewall'd area? If you're not in the area that the firewall covers you're not authenticated.

Comment: Yes I did redirect it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the InteractiveLoginEvent to happen for the user to be logged in.

```
// Here, "public" is the name of the firewall in your security.yml
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "public", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

// Fire the login event
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

Comment: Where is `$user` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
```

I applied above solution in a couple of our projects. One worked but another did not.

The final solution is using security_context_name instead of firewall_name in below line. Then it worked on every project.

```
$session->set('_security_'.$security_context_name, serialize($token));
```

Thanks for one of my colleagues pointing it out for me.