# Symfony2 auto-login after user registration

Tags: php, symfony

I have seen some posts in this regard, specifically [Auto-Login via URL with symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311586/auto-login-via-url-with-symfony2) (which I can't use because I do not know what needs to go into $request) and [Automatic post-registration user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication). I tried the latter, but it is not logging in.

Code from security.yml

```
 firewalls:
    admin_login_firewall:
      pattern:    ^/admin/login$
      anonymous:  ~
    admin:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        form_login:
            login_path:  admin_login
            check_path:  admin_login_check
            default_target_path: admin_dashboard  
        logout:
            path:   admin_logout
            target: admin_login
        http_basic:
            realm: "Licensing Admin Portal"
    member_login_firewall:
      pattern:    ^/members/login$
      anonymous:  ~
    members:
        pattern:    ^/members
        form_login:
            login_path:  member_login
            check_path:  member_login_check
            default_target_path: member_dashboard  
        logout:
            path:   member_logout
            target: home
        http_basic:
            realm: "Licensing Member Portal"        


encoders:
    Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/members/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/members/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Code snippet from Controller function saveUserAction():

```
    ... // Code preceding this point creates user entity and sets all fields
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if (empty($data['user_id'])) $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    if (!empty($organization)) $this->linkOrganizationUserAction($organization,$user, true);

    if (isset($data['registering']))
    {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'members', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));
    }

    return $this->createJsonResponse($user);
```

I am trying to log in to the members firewall. I do not know enough about this to troubleshoot. Most of this is just copy/paste/edit. Any help / explanation would be greatly appreciated. I also read the article under [Symfony2 auto-login after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378774/symfony2-auto-login-after-registration), but I do not see the significance of this, as I do not need have users logged in accross different firewalls, and just need the user logged in under the members firewall.

One thing that I DID notice, is that the user entity is having its salt field populated when persiting to the database, even though I did not set a salt and I cannot see anything auto-setting the salt. I am not yet using the salt as I am not yet encrypting my passwords (just trying to get it working with plain text passwords first), and when trying to log in with a created user (which does get created, just not getting logged in) I cannot log in unless I clear the salt on the user. I don't know if this has anything to do with the fact that the auto-login is not working.

Comment: If anybody requires any additional information/code, I will be happy to submit it.

Comment: "which I can't use because I do not know what needs to go into $request" - The Request, which you can retrieve by using `$this->getRequest()` in a controller (deprecated as of 2.4) or `Request $request` in your controller parameters (with Request being `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`)

Comment: Wouter J, what I normally do to access form data is `$data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();` which gives be the form data in array $data. I understand that $this-getRequest() gets a Request object, but does that request object require any specific form data to be set? For instance, for this autologin to work, would _username and _password need to be set? If so, and they are not set during the form submission, is it possible to set them in PHP before invoking the InteractiveLogin event?

Comment: You can use `$this->getRequest()->request->add(array('_username' => ..., '_password' => ...));` to set $_POST data and replace `->request` by `->query` to set $_GET data

Comment: Ok, so I tried the InteractiveLoginEvent, but still no dice, still not logging in and keeps redirecting to the login page (as there is no logged in user). Symfony2 console at the bottom of the page also confirms no user logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here was with the line `$this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));`. The "_main" of "security_main" is also the firewall that you are authenticating against. So it should have been "_security_members". After changing it the code worked as is.